# What happens if one of my series in the VAR is not stationary?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, vector-autoregression, augmented-dickey-fuller, differencing

I have a VAR model that comprehends 6 series.
Only one of them is non-stationary even after taking the 1st difference.
Do I need to take the 2nd difference?
My concern is to approximate too much the other 5 series.
I used the augmented Dickey-Fuller test.

Comment: Hi @Chiara Saini. VAR is a stationary model, so yes you would have to second difference your I(2) variable. However, you would have to ask yourself if you wished to have a I(2) stationary variable in your model, and what this would represent in terms of real world interpretation? For example, would it be more desirable to have another type of transformation such as the logged first difference, and evaluate whether this is stationary?

Comment: In addition to what @EB3112 wrote, let us not forget that nonstationarity may be caused by things other than a unit root, and thus differencing a nonstationary time series is not always the right answer. Chiara, consider posting a plot of the nonstationary series (original, i.e. untransformed, and perhaps also first-differenced). What subject-matter area do these time series concern? What do you know about the processes behind, are they likely to have a unit root or several unit roots?